# Encoding set values in $o(n)$ memory

Tags: data-structures

Apache Spark, a distributed computation framework, has a construct called accumulators which are global variables with an associative addition action. These can be used to aggregate statistics during the computation process. The problem with these variables is that parallel tasks can fail without "rolling back" the value of the accumulator, so at the end of the process if any tasks were re-run, the accumulator will have a larger value than it should have in reality.

In my case I want to count the amount of elements I filter out in my process.

If I simply use an integer/long counter and increment it each time I filter out an element, I will possibly get inaccurate results because of the problem previously described.

An idea I had is to use a set as the accumulator, collecting in it all the unique identifiers of the elements I filtered out, then getting its size at the end of the process.
This will produce an accurate result but will have a performance impact of storing a possibly very large list of identifiers in memory.

Thus I am curious if there is any mathematical construct I can use which has the following properties:

1. Occupies $o(n)$ of memory. By that I mean that its size will grow very little a a function of the size of the dataset I am running on.
2. Has an associative "addition" method that recognizes when a value added to it was already added previously
3. Has a "size" method that returns the amount of unique values added to it.

A set satisfies the second and third constraint but not the first, however a set has the property of retrieving its values, which I do not need. Is it maybe possible to achieve all three when this is not needed?

I know this is probably overkill for a programming problem but at this point I am just curious if anything like this exists.

thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with Apache Spark and how accumulators work, but I am just wondering if it is possible for you to determine the computation that failed and then simply have a counter for it, which you can use to correct the inaccuracies for the other counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such data structure can exist that satisfies (1) and (2): if $n$ arbitrary elements can be added to it, and it has to keep track of whether each of them has been seen already or not, then it has to have at least $2^n$ configurations, and therefore maintain $\Theta(n)$ memory at least (i.e. keeping a single bit for each element it has seen or not).

Comment: Possibly, you want to say $\Omega(n)$ at least..

Comment: @zkutch good catch, fixed

Answer (score 0):

A possible strategy to check the final value of your accumulator is accurate would probably be to subdivide into multiple smaller accumulators. This way you can separate the tasks into multiple steps.

Checking the value of each step will allow you to be able to confirm the accuracy of your program running in a parallel computed environment. If you are able to check the value of these subdivided tasks is not accurate to the value they are supposed to represent, the system can rerun the task for this particular section before adding back into the total value.

This will ensure the required time to fix the adjusted value <O(n) and allow to implement security measures to ensure any miscalculated values are checked without having to check every value again in a single step, thereby running the same calculation with equal to the same amount of risk.

If I understand your question correctly, this is a general pseudo approach I may consider. There may be solutions not considered, it depends on the language and environment you are working in.

Parallel computations should be for the most part reliable.

Comment: Does subdivision into multiple smaller accumulators work for a *set*, i.e., a group of distinct elements?